# PHP: $ get inside

Tags: php

So I want Get the part of url into a php This is my script

I want `$_GET["m"]`

Insidr of

```
<?php include('links.php'); ?>
<?php echo $title ?>

<?php include('links.php'); ?>
<ul class="pageitem"><li class="textbox"><p> the codes go here</p></li></ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is the question?

Comment: Don't include link.php more than once

Comment: @Jonah Allibone: You have no idea what **`links.php`** does. It could very well be intended to be included twice. That's up to the OP to decide and has nothing to do with the question at hand.

Answer (score 3):

Teh codes are in dere:

```
<?php include('links.php'); ?>
<?php echo $title ?>

<?php include('links.php'); ?>
<ul class="pageitem"><li class="textbox"><p><?php echo $_GET["m"]; ?></p></li></ul>
```

But you seemed to have `$title` printing just fine. Is this what you're looking for? I'm not exactly sure of what you are asking.

Comment: @Jonah Allibone: You have no idea what **`links.php`** does. It could very well be intended to be included twice. That's up to the OP to decide and has nothing to do with the question at hand.

Comment: @AndrewMoore STOP INCLUDING YOUR COMMENT MORE THAN ONCE! ;)

Comment: @Phil: Jonah also posted her comment in this discussion and it has since been deleted.

Answer (score 2):

`$_GET` is a [**Superglobal**](http://php.net/superglobals) in PHP. You can use it anywhere...

```
<?php include('links.php'); ?>
<?php echo $title; ?>

<?php include('links.php'); /* Is the double include intended? */ ?>
<ul class="pageitem">
  <li class="textbox">
    <p>
      I like a having my <?php echo $_GET['m']; ?>
      in the morning. Who doesn't
      like <?php echo $_GET['m']; ?> in the morning anyway?
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```